# change the currently being displayed string from an array

Tags: c++

I would like to change the current string displayed on the screen by pressing buttons. for example:

I have an array of strings here:

```
std::string test[] = { "hey", "how", "are", "you" };
```

then i have some code here to change the current displayed string from the array:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    //display one string left from the array
else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    //display string next to the current one in array

std::cout << test;
```

so what kind of code should i put to the commented parts???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Are you using [tag:ncurses]? Is this being run in a terminal so you want to clear the screen and display a new string? How are you keeping track of which string you're currently displaying? This question is far too broad as it stands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have an atribute or a variable where you save the index of the current string.

```
int index = 1;
```

for example.

Then you have to check if the index is valid in commented parts.

```
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    if (index == test.size())
    {
        index = test.size() - 1;
    } else {
        index++;
    }

std::cout << test[index];
```

```
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    if (index > 0)
    {
        index--;
    }
std::cout << test[index];
```

In the end, it should look something like this.

Comment: YOu could improve that answer by ensuring `std::cout << test[index];` is called exactly once, instead of being copy/pasted inside each code path.

Comment: Both snippets are wrong. `sizeof(test)` returns `4*sizeof(std::string)`, not size of the array and both ifs are checking value of `index` before it is incremented/decremented.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the code should be ok now